# Conditionally compute value in ConcurentHashMap and replace it at some time intervals

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

In my application there is a shared cache service. It's accessed by multiple threads, so it must be thread safe. I have implemented it with HashMap as I synchronized the getOrCreateToken() method but I made implementation with ConcurentHashMap as well. My problem is that I don't want to perform service.authenticateWithoutCache() if there is no need to (this is API limitation, I am obligated to make requests only if it is actually needed). However,if multiple threads pass the marker **!!!MARKER!!!**, several new NEEDLES tokens will be issued. computeIfAbsent will not work, because the token should be reissued at some time intervals. I want to find a way to replace old ticket only once when the condition is met, and not every time when multiple threads enters the if statement?

Note: In implementation with synchronized HashMap  this is easy to be achieved, because synchronized block guarantees that only one thread is executing the block.

```
    private static Map<String, TokenResponse> cachedKeys = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static TokenResponse getOrCreateToken(OAuthService service)
        throws IOException {

    String accessTokenKey = constructAccessTokenKey(configuration);
    TokenResponse token = cachedKeys.get(accessTokenKey);
    if (token == null) {
        TokenResponse alreadyThereToken = cachedKeys.computeIfAbsent(accessTokenKey,
                key -> service.authenticateWithoutCache());
        return alreadyThereToken;
    } else {
        Instant now = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        Instant createdAt = token.getCreatedAt().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();

        long minutes = accessTokenExpiredMinutes(createdAt, now);
        //!!!MARKER!!!
        if (minutes > 90) {
            //Here several threads can execute this line
            //And service.authenticateWithoutCache() will be called several times and this should not happen. 
            //If I execute computeIfAbsent it will be evaluated only the 
            //first time a thread reach this code
            // and it won't be updated anymore even if access token expires.
            return cachedKeys.compute(accessTokenKey, (key, value) -> 
                             service.authenticateWithoutCache() 

            });
        }

    }
    return token;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking or what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the token generation into a synchronized block, try to get it again in that block and retry it in each thread. Something like:

```
TokenResponse getOrCreateFor(String accessTokenKey){
  TokenResponse token = cachedKeys.get(accessTokenKey);
  if (token != null)
    return token;

  synchronized(cachedKeys){
    token = cachedKeys.get(accessTokenKey);
    if (token != null)
      return token;
    return cachedKeys.computeIfAbsent(accessTokenKey,
             key -> service.authenticateWithoutCache());
  }
}
```

If you just clear the token before if the timeout occurred and use that method afterwards everything should be fine :-)

That way only the creation of the tokens is synchronized, everything else is parallel.

If you want to get tokens parallel for different users you need to have something like a HashSet for accesTokenKeys each with its own per accesTokenKey object for locking the authenticateWithoutCache. But access to that has to be threadsafe too, maybe there is a good non locking solution.. But I would delay that until needed.

Comment: Hi ! Several things here. 
1. I don't understand what you mean by "clear the token before..."
2. What is the purpose to execute put() after computeIfAbsent(), when computeIfAbsent also put an element at specified key

Comment: 2. You are right :-)  I thought it's just a compute token at that point... I will fix that